# I'm developing two apps and for one of apps I copied a debug key-store from other machine. Will it reflect any problems for second app?

Tags: android, android-layout, debugging, android-studio, keystore

Developing two apps using android studio. Will hanging debug.keystore reflect the other app.

Comment: So, Do I need to change the debug.keystore for the second app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No,  nothing bad will happen. 
Usually every machine gets it's own debug keystore,  some people (team members)   even reuse it and share it between themselves in case you want to share the debugabble version of your app. 
In this case if you and all your team members use the same keys (that means two keystores)  for debug and release signing. 
Users and testers wont have to uninstall and reinstall the app due to colliding signatures if they get the app from different developers or CI servers but just simply update.